# Boost::python example on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, boost, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to build the boost:python example on ubuntu 12.04.
I installed the libraries from package manager (not from source).
I also have not used boost before, and haven't set up any environment variables for this (BOOST_BUILD_PATH is unset).
I get this error :

```
/usr/share/doc/libboost1.46-doc/examples/libs/python/example/tutorial$ bjam --debug-configuration
notice: found boost-build.jam at /usr/share/doc/libboost1.46-doc/examples/libs/python/example/boost-build.jam
Unable to load Boost.Build: could not find build system.
---------------------------------------------------------
/usr/share/doc/libboost1.46-doc/examples/libs/python/example/boost-build.jam attempted to load the build system by invoking
'boost-build ../../../tools/build/v2 ;'
but we were unable to find "bootstrap.jam" in the specified directory
or in BOOST_BUILD_PATH (searching /usr/share/doc/libboost1.46-doc/examples/libs/python/example/../../../tools/build/v2, /usr/share/boost-build).
Please consult the documentation at 'http://www.boost.org'.
```

How can I fix it ? 
Where should I point BOOST_BUILD_PATH to ?

Comment: I've unpacked them from source on my Lucid box, into ~/boost_1_49_0, and there's bootstrap.jam in `~/boost_1_49_0/tools/build/v2`. Is there any specific reason you do not want to just grab the tarball and unpack it?

Comment: From my experience mixing package manager installed libraries with tarballs leads to a mess, so I wanted to avoid installing from tarball. $ locate bootstrap.jam gives 
/usr/share/boost-build/kernel/bootstrap.jam Is this the correct bootstrap.jam. Did you install from tarball on 12.04 as well ?

Comment: I'm still on 10.04, so I can't say anything about 12.04 really. So my case was simple: I needed a version of boost newer than the one available in the repositories, so --- download the tarball, unpack it, and hey presto

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and I found the solution here:

http://jayrambhia.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/configuring-boostpython-and-hello-boost/

It turns out that you do not need to use bjam at all. A makefile suffices. I will repeat the the solution from the above link here:

1.) Install the libboost-python package

2.) Create a hello world source file called 'hello_ext.c':

```
char const* greet()
{
    return "hello, world";
}

#include<boost/python.hpp>
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
   using namespace boost::python;
   def("greet",greet);
}
```

3.) Create a makefile:

```
PYTHON_VERSION = 2.7
PYTHON_INCLUDE = /usr/include/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)
# location of the Boost Python include files and library
BOOST_INC = /usr/include
BOOST_LIB = /usr/lib
# compile mesh classes
TARGET = hello_ext
$(TARGET).so: $(TARGET).o
    g++ -shared -Wl,--export-dynamic $(TARGET).o -L$(BOOST_LIB) -lboost_python -L/usr   /lib/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)/config -lpython$(PYTHON_VERSION) -o $(TARGET).so
$(TARGET).o: $(TARGET).c
    g++ -I$(PYTHON_INCLUDE) -I$(BOOST_INC) -fPIC -c $(TARGET).c
```

4.) make

```
make
```

5.) Ready to use. In python:

```
import hello_ext
print hello_ext.greet()
```

---

Edited to include a tab.

Comment: gotta have those indents in the makefile....put a tab before both lines starting with g++

Comment: Great answer. Makes you wonder why the boost-python tutorial takes you down a path of mucking around with Jamroot, bjam, a user-config.jam and other things when a simple Makefile will demo exactly how to build it. A minor point is that the hello_ext.c is a .cpp file in the Boost tutorial and so this requires $(TARGET).cpp instead. This builds perfectly on 15.04 vivid for me.

Comment: Also there's a space between `-L/usr` and `/lib/python$PYTHON ...` that needs to be deleted.

Comment: when running make command it shows this error:  g++ -shared -Wl,--export-dynamic hello_ext.o -L/usr/lib -lboost_python -L/usr   /lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -o hello_ext.so
g++: error: /lib/python2.7/config: No such file or directory
MakeFile:9: recipe for target 'hello_ext.so' failed
make: *** [hello_ext.so] Error 1